# Redux Toolkit - Setting initial state using RTK Query

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to set the initial state of my contactSlice.ts with an async function using RTK Query.

I've read the docs and searched online but I didn't find a suitable solution for this problem.

**contactsAPI.ts:**

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
import { Contact } from '../models/contact.model';

export const contactsApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: "contactsApi",
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "http://localhost:3006/" }),
    tagTypes: ['Contact'],
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        contacts: builder.query<Contact[], void>({
            query: () => '/contacts',
            providesTags: ['Contact']
        }),
        contact: builder.query<Contact, string>({
            query: (id) => `/contacts/${ id }`,
            providesTags: ['Contact']
        }),
        addContact: builder.mutation<{}, Contact>({
            query: contact => ({
                url: '/contacts',
                method: 'POST',
                body: contact    
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Contact']
        }),
        updateContact: builder.mutation<void, Contact>({
            query: ({id, ...rest}) => ({
                url: `/contacts/${ id }`,
                method: 'PUT',
                body: rest
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Contact']
        }),
        deleteContact: builder.mutation<void, string>({
            query: (id) => ({
                url: `/contacts/${ id }`,
                method: 'DELETE',
            }),
            invalidatesTags: ['Contact']
        })
    })
})

export const {
    useContactsQuery,
    useContactQuery,
    useAddContactMutation,
    useUpdateContactMutation,
    useDeleteContactMutation
} = contactsApi;
```

**contactSlice.ts**:

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Contact } from '../models/contact.model';
import type { RootState } from '../store';

// Define a type for the slice state
interface ContactState {
    value: Contact[]
}

// Define the initial state using that type
const initialState: ContactState = {
    value: //enter async function here
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'contact',
    // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
    initialState,
    reducers: {}
})

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

I want to set the initialState value using the useContactsQuery from the contactsAPI.ts but I can't figure how how to do it async and enable cathing errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this action by using the extraReducers like in this [example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers).

Although you should consider **not** to do it for more consistent [Single Source of Truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_source_of_truth).

Instead, you should use your rtk API as the store that will be invalidated and refetch when it is needed too automatically.

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { Contact } from '../models/contact.model';
import type { RootState } from '../store';

// Define a type for the slice state
interface ContactState {
    value: Contact[]
}

// Define the initial state using that type
const initialState: ContactState = {
    value: //enter async function here
}

export const counterSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'contact',
    // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
    initialState,
    reducers: {},
   extraReducers: (builder) => {
      builder.addMatcher(
        api.endpoints.contacts.matchFulfilled,
        (state, { payload }) => {
           state = payload
       }
    )
  },
})

export default counterSlice.reducer
```

see more:

[RTK Query: dispatch inside query or mutations - github](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1509#issuecomment-919255436)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by using the rtk API as the store? Because I want to have a local cache as well by using the contactSlice.
And in the code snippet you wrote is it setting the state on initializing the app?

Comment: Your question was how to do it and for that the code snippet  but rtk query recommendation isn't to store the api content in the regular sate

Comment: So if I've understood correctly - upon using useContactsQuery() from the contactsApi it will automatically update the state in the contactSlice.ts? 
But this way isn't recommended by the SSOT concept. 
Then what is the recommended way to initiate a state with an async function?

Comment: Yes, If you want to create also slice for saving the contacts, you can use the extraReducers like in the answer above